Quarkus/JBeret: Is there a way to prevent the initialization of the database with the ddl script?
We are using Flyway to initialize our database. However, it seems that JBeret is initializing the database too and this causes issues with our database.
I see that the functionality to create the tables is located in the JdbcRepository:
https://github.com/jberet/jsr352/blob/de767907e1f9637b677bf70e20cfe220864cadf4/jberet-core/src/main/java/org/jberet/repository/JdbcRepository.java#L198
I looked in the JBeret and Quarkus/JBeret documentation pages, but couldn't find anything.
Is there a way to prevent JBeret from initializing the database ?

Sounds like a valid issue/feature request for Quarkus JBeret (github.com).

JBeret tries to detect if the tables already exist, and if not then it proceeds to create tables. See here. If you can make sure this conditioin is true (tables exist), then JBeret will skip the db init part.

First of all, thanks for your answer, it brings some clarity.
However, my situation was a bit special because JBeret was creating the tables before Flyway started. This normally doesn't happen in real world, but I was using the devservices provided by Quarkus to start the database as a container. Maybe there is a way to intervene in this lifecycle and run flyway just after the database was started, but I didn't find how to do it.
My solution was to provide an empty ddl file for the jberet tables with:
quarkus.jberet.repository.jdbc.ddl-file.
